# Root Cause of paramiko.ssh_exception.ChannelException: (1, 'Administratively prohibited')

Tags: python, ssh, paramiko

I've been trying to use paramiko lately, I occasionally hit the below error.

I'm unable to root cause the error. Is it because I've exhausted the number of open ssh connections to the server? If so, how can I view the existing connections?

```
  File "/sw/packages/python/current/lib/python2.7/site-
  packages/paramiko/client.py", line 420, in exec_command
  chan = self._transport.open_session(timeout=timeout)
  File "/sw/packages/python/current/lib/python2.7/site-
  packages/paramiko/transport.py", line 704, in open_session
  timeout=timeout)
  File "/sw/packages/python/current/lib/python2.7/site-
  packages/paramiko/transport.py", line 836, in open_channel
  raise e
  paramiko.ssh_exception.ChannelException: (1, 'Administratively 
  prohibited')
```